# How to pass react.js data via createContainer like meteor.js or relay.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, meteor, relayjs

I like the concept of receiving data in `react.js` from meteor and `relay.js`.
For example `meteor.js`, in `createContainer` I get data from localstorage:

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (<div>{this.props.doc}</div>);
  }
}
export default createContainer( () => {
  subscribe('doc');
  return { doc:Docs.find() };
}, App);
```

Or example form `relay.js` where in `createContainer` data data obtained from the `graphQL` assigned `props`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var name = this.props.tea;
    return (<li key={name}>{name}</li>);
  }
}
App = Relay.createContainer(App, {
  fragments: {
    tea:() => Relay.QL`fragment on Tea {name}`,
  },
});
```

How to make such a function that will receive data from `websocket`?
I can imagine code like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (<div>{this.props.doc}</div>);
  }
}
export default createContainer( () => {
  return { doc:Docs.find() };
}, App);

ReactDOM.render(<App>, document.getElementById('root'));


function createContainer(options, callback) { 
   var props;
   var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8081");
   socket.onmessage = function(event) {
       props = event.data;
   };
   <callback data={props}>
}
```

I do not fully understand how best to write so please help.

Comment: That's a great question. I am interested in learning about this, too.

Comment: @Yumiko I kind of found the answer to this question below answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked like it worked in a `meteor.js`. And I understand how it should work. Just need to make a function that will return a `react.js` component. And pass the parameters and the component itself and all. In  `createContainer` function it is already possible to get data from `websockets` or take out from `indexDB`.

if very simple it might look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
export default function createContainer(options = {}, Component) {
  return React.createClass({
    displayName:'DataContainer',    
    render() { return <Component data=options />; },
  });
}
```

the complete code of the component in the meteor looks like:

https://github.com/jedwards1211/react-meteor-data/blob/master/src/createContainer.js